# Origin of term "doublespeak"

Tags: etymology, history

I googled "doublespeak", and I [got this:](http://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php?title=Talk%3aDoublespeak)

> A false Etemology?
>   The word "doublespeak" wasn't "coined in the early 1950's" (I'm on shaky ground here but I doubt if anyone can show me a cite much before 1990)
>
> I guess this could be checked in LexusNexus or similar. Mememe 14:28, 26 Sep 2005 (EDT)
>   Interestingly, this apparently goes back to 1974:

I also looked in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doublespeak), but it gave the date of:

> Origin: 
>   1950–55; double + speak, by analogy with doublethink

I looked further and came up with this:

> Because of my erroneous memory, I thought that 'doublespeak' actually appeared and hence was defined in 1984. But from the Wikipedia entry, I learn that it "was coined in the early 1950s", and is "often incorrectly attributed to George Orwell" (as was done by me).

Which stated that George Orwell did not come up with this phrase. But then the following really [confused me:](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/doublespeakterm.htm)

> •"Doublespeak is not a term invented by George Orwell, but we surely nod to him for its origin, since he did invent 'doublethink' and 'newspeak' for his political novel 1984"
>   (Paul Wasserman and Don Hausrath, Weasel Words: The Dictionary of American Doublespeak. Capital Books, 2006)

So what exactly is the origin of the term "doublespeak"?

Comment: You know that *1984* was published in 1949, right?  And it was about the future?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary doesn't have *doublespeak* as a separate entry; I can only make an educated guess. The word **double-talk** already existed in 1938, according to the OED, and was originally American. But apparently it meant simply "deliberate gibberish" then, i.e. not merely ambiguous language, but nonsense talk that listeners were *supposed* to know meant nothing, uttered to comical or artistic effect.

> 1938 *New York Panorama* (Amer. Guide
>   Ser.) vi. 156 Of late a humorously
>   conceived system of language
>   corruption called **double talk** ... has made
>   itself felt.  *Ibid*. 157 **Double talk**
>   is created by mixing
>   plausible-sounding gibberish into
>   ordinary conversation, the speaker
>   keeping a straight face or dead pan
>   and enunciating casually or off the
>   cuff.
>
> 1941 *Time* 16 June 61/1 Thirteen
>   recorded versions of this pandemic
>   **double-talk** ballad are available.
>
> 1945 H. I. Phillips *Private Purkey's
>   Private Peace* xxii. 129 We got the
>   right slant on bullies, greaseballs,
>   **double talkers**, supermen, and dopes.
>
> 1948 Auden *Age of Anxiety* vi. 125 And
>   all species of space respond in our
>   own Contradictory dialect, the **double
>   talk** Of ambiguous bodies.

After Orwell's famous novel *1984*, published in 1948/1949, *double-talk* apparently acquired the (additional?) meaning "deceiving language", i.e. language that is deliberately ambiguous, or language that appears to mean one thing but in fact means another.

> 1950 *Amer. Speech* XXV. 190 Back in
>   Tsarist times Lenin and his associates
>   inaugurated this **double-talk** and
>   double-writing—especially the
>   latter—in order to deceive the Tsarist
>   censors and police.
>
> 1952 C. Day Lewis tr. Virgil's
>   *Aeneid* ix. 203 You'll find no Atridae here, no **double-talking**
>   Ulysses.

This is probably based on Orwell's *newspeak* and *doublethink*. His novel was (partly) a critique of the practice and propaganda of the totalitarian regimes of his time, Fascist Germany and Stalinist Russia.

**Newspeak** is new language invented by politicians as propaganda, in order to influence people's thinking by changing their language (one of the principal mechanisms studied by [Postmodernist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism) philosophers and sociologists). The word is invented by politicians in the novel and is an instance of itself. By drastically reducing vocabulary, and making new, simpler words from the remainder, they hoped to control the people more effectively. Many modern euphemisms could be called, and are often called, *newspeak*, like "differently abled" and "Secretary of Defence".

> 1949 ‘G. Orwell’ *Nineteen Eighty-Four*
>   i. 51 Syme was a philologist, a
>   specialist in **Newspeak**. Indeed, he was
>   one of the enormous team of experts
>   now engaged in compiling the Eleventh
>   Edition of the Newspeak Dictionary. 
>   *Ibid*. ii. 133 Do you know the Newspeak
>   word goodthinkful?  *Ibid*. App. 299
>   Newspeak was the official language of
>   Oceania and had been devised to meet
>   the ideological needs of Ingsoc, or
>   English Socialism. In the year 1984
>   there was not as yet anyone who used
>   Newspeak as his sole means of
>   communication, either in speech or
>   writing.

**Doublethink** is somewhat related to what modern psychology calls *cognitive dissonance*: first accepting one fact as true, then another, contradictory fact—without critical self-assessment, which would ordinarily result in elimination of one fact or the other. Orwell's politicians try to effect *doublethink* by means of using and propagating ambiguous language.

> 1949 ‘G. Orwell’ *Nineteen Eighty-Four*
>   i. iii. 37 His mind slid away into the
>   labyrinthine world of **doublethink**. To
>   know and not to know, to be conscious
>   of complete truthfulness while telling
>   carefully constructed lies, to hold
>   simultaneously two opinions which
>   cancelled out, knowing them to be
>   contradictory and believing in both of
>   them, to use logic against logic, to
>   repudiate morality while laying claim
>   to it, to believe that democracy was
>   impossible and that the Party was the
>   guardian of democracy.

Considering the change in meaning of *double-talk* soon after the publication of Orwell's novel, and the emergence of **doublespeak** to mean the same a few years later, your sources (reasonably) assume that the word was deliberately coined as a (semi-)portmanteau of Orwell's *newspeak* and *doublethink*. The OED has 1957 as its earliest quotation:

> 1957 ‘M. Buttle’ *Sweeniad* ii. 55 In
>   the literary weeklies, the languages
>   of criticism and theology have become
>   one and book reviews all sound like
>   sermons written in the most holy
>   ‘***Double-Speak**’.
>
> 1961 W. Kaufmann in G. E. Myers *Self,
>   Relig. & Metaphysics* 99 The
>   theologians have a way of redefining
>   terms in rather odd ways, and
>   frequently engage in something best
>   called **double-speak**: their
>   utterances are designed to communicate
>   contradictory views to different
>   listeners and readers.

The asterisk and quotation marks in the first quote might indicate that the word was then quite new and explained in a footnote.

Comment: This essay is doubleplusgood, Cerberus.

Comment: Obligatory [Google Ngram for doublespeak vs. doubletalk](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=doublespeak%2C+doubletalk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows 'doubletalk' very popular in the forties, before _1984_ was published, but then taken over by 'doublespeak' by the 1980's. Also my spellchecker recognizes 'doublespeak' but not 'doubletalk'.

Comment: @Mitch: Ah, yes. I've added *double speak*, which had an even higher peak, also around 1945-1960; it them began to drop, but is now regaining some momentum. http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=doublespeak%2Cdoubletalk%2Cdouble+talk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: Interesting -- so in fact the "Orwellian" meaning may have just been an extension of an already existing meaning. Nonetheless, it does seem that people begain to associate the word with Orwell soon after the publication of 1984.

Comment: "Doublespeak" now has its own entry in the OED: "= double-talk n. 2; cf. -speak suffix   and doublethink n.". 1957 is still their earliest (I'll send them the 1950 from Hansard) but now the asterisk is gone.

Answer (score 4):

Searching Google Books for "doublespeak" in publications in the 1950s, there are apparently various instances from publications in the mid 1950s, apparently already with an association with Orwell.

And see this apparent instance from a 1950 House of Commons debate (http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/commons/1950/nov/02/debate-on-the-address#S5CV0480P0_19501102_HOC_80):

> Perhaps it is yet another example of what the late George Orwell in his book, which hon. Members may or may not have read, entitled "Nineteen Eighty-four" called "double speak."

So even if Orwell didn't literally use the term, it does seem that it was originally coined as a "pseudo-Orwellianism".

Comment: Very interesting link to the HoC debate!

Answer (score 0):

The first use I can find is in a book called *[Varieties of present-day English](http://books.google.com/books?id=brtZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22doublespeak%22&dq=%22doublespeak%22&hl=en&ei=yDboTbw7zsqIArngpKMB&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBDgU)*
 (Richard W. Bailey, Jay L. Robinson - Macmillan, 1973):

> ...black folks talk like white folk on
>   all occasions which the Northern
>   Powers thought it worth their while to
>   regulate.  This was the origin of bidialectalism,
>   biloquialism, or - in "good plain
>   Anglo-Saxon" - doublespeak.

This first usage clearly intends to convey a conscious switching of dialects depending on audience; the (now) more usual meaning - a mash-up of Orwell's "doublethink" and "Newspeak", intending to convey using "[language that is grossly deceptive, evasive, euphemistic, confusing, or self-centered](http://www.ncte.org/volunteer/groups/publiclangcom/doublespeakaward)", seems to have first appeared the next year (1974) when the (U.S.) National Council of Teachers of English formed a Committee on Public Doublespeak.

A.M. Tibbetts, writing in the NCTE's magazine "[College English](http://www.jstor.org/pss/376261)" in 1978, said

> The Committee, of course,
>   owes a great debt to George Orwell. 
>   Its operative term, *doublespeak*, is
>   derived from [*Nineteen Eighty-Four*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0452284236). 
>   An early resolution (passed in 1971 at
>   the annual convention of the NCTE),
>   which led to the creation of the
>   Committee, quoted Orwell's remark that
>   "language is often used as an
>   instrument of social control."  The
>   Committee's publications resonate with
>   Orwell's name, and allusions to him
>   abound in statements on doublespeak.

So, although Orwell himself never used the term, I think it's fairly clear that (in this second meaning at least) the etymology is his.

Comment: No, it's certainly much older than this! (See my answer for an apparent example from 1950.)

Comment: @Neil - I see what my problem was:  Googling the compound word as opposed to the phrase...  In